# Find all variables in a Tensorflow subgraph defined by a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Tensor `net` that is the result of a computational graph. The graph involves some variables (e.g. `weights1`, `biases1`) which hold parameters of the models. Is there a way to obtain the variables given `net`? Something like:

`[weights1, biases1] = tf.get_all_variables_for_op(net)`

Comment: We have different kinds of variables. You can use `tf.model_variables`, or `tf.global_variables` that might be doing what you are looking for.

Comment: @drpng I did not know the difference between global and model variables. The documentation is not too verbose about the different variable types or I am looking in a wrong place for it. But, anyway, both functions are argument-less. Thus, having several models (e.g. networks) I cannot easily find variables concerning only a given one.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you have some nodes, and you want to traverse the graph to find all variables on which each node depends? (They may be overlapping) If so, then I think you have to use `tf.graph_util.extract_subgraph(net)`, then traverse all nodes of the subgraph, and check if that is a variable (look in [`graph_util_impl.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py#L47)), then add it to an array.

Comment: @drpng Indeed, there is [graph_util.extract_sub_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/816ecb7a342c25c19daa8b19627346e1fb38e56f/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util.py#L127), which looks promising. But how to import the graph_util module in the first place?

Comment: You don't need to import it, it's available as `tf.graph_util.extract_sub_graph`.

Comment: Hmm. I have graph_util.py on my system ("site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util.py"), but I get `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'graph_util'`. I have the most recent binary version (v0.11.0rc2-4-gf413209-dirty), so maybe this is only available on master?

Comment: Strange.  It's probably a bug, fixed at head. you could try `from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util`.